# Why am I receiving an uncaught type error from my KendoUI taghelper grid in my ASP.NET Core application?

Tags: asp.net-core, kendo-ui

I have a tag helper KendoUI grid, the grid is filterable but when I added the filter properties I get an error message back of:

```
Uncaught TypeError: t is undefined    kendo.all.js:96768:38
```

If I remove the line of code that sets the grid as filterable it works but there is no filtering capability.

```
 <filterable enabled="true" mode="row" />
```

Looking at this closely, removing the property of `mode=¬row"` causes the error to go away however, as above there are no filter capabilities.

Here is the complete code for my grid as it stands:

```
<kendo-grid name="addVesselPositionGrid" deferred="false">
    <datasource type="DataSourceTagHelperType.Ajax" page-size="10">
        <transport>
            <read url="/Core/ReadVessels" />
        </transport>
        <schema>
            <model id="Id">
                <fields>
                     <field name="Id" editable="false"></field>
                     <field name="Name" type="Name" />
                     <field name="IMO" type="IMO" />
                 </fields>
             </model>
         </schema>
     </datasource>                                    
     <sortable enabled="true" />
     <pageable enabled="true" />                                    
     <filterable enabled="true" mode="row" />
     <columns>
         <column field="Id" title="Id" hidden="true"></column>
         <column field="Name" title="Name">
             <filterable multi="true">
                 <cell operator="Contains" suggestion-operator="Contains"></cell>
             </filterable>
        </column>
        <column field="IMO" title="IMO"></column>                                
    </columns>
</kendo-grid>
```

I've searched the documentation but I can't find any information on this, looking at my code it seems to be accurate.  Any ideas?